# Map Pandas Series Containing key/value pairs to a new columns with data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, lambda, split

I have a dataframe containing a pandas series (column 2) as below:

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | Requested By = John Doe 1\n Requested On = 12 October 2021\n Comments = This is a generic request | INC29192 |
| 1251 | NaN | INC18217 |
| 1918 | Requested By = John Doe 2\n Requested On = 2 September 2021\n Comments = This is another generic request | INC19281 |

I'm struggling to extract, split and map column 2 data to a series of new column names with the appropriate data for that record (where possible, that is where there is data available as I have NaNs).

The Desired output is something like (where Ive dropped the column 3 data for legibility):

| column 1 | column 3 | Requested By | Requested On | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | INC29192 | John Doe 1 | 12 October 2021 | This is a generic request |
| 1251 | INC18217 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1918 | INC19281 | John Doe 2 | 2 September 2021 | This is another generic request |

I have spent quite some time, trying various approaches, from lambda functions to comprehensions to explode methods but havent quite found a solution that provides the desired output.

Comment: Please add data as a code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would convert `column 2` values to dictionaries and then convert them to Dataframes and join them to your df:

```
df['column 2'] = df['column 2'].apply(lambda x: 
                                       {y.split(' = ',1)[0]:y.split(' = ',1)[1]
                                       for y in x.split(r'\n ')}
                                       if not pd.isna(x) else {})
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['column 2'].values.tolist())).drop('column 2', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   column 1  column 3 Requested By      Requested On                         Comments
0      1123  INC29192   John Doe 1   12 October 2021        This is a generic request
1      1251  INC18217          NaN               NaN                              NaN
2      1918  INC19281   John Doe 2  2 September 2021  This is another generic request
```